# How about adding a Real Estate SE site?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

I looked through all the Stack Exchange sites and didn't find one that would be good for posting questions related to searching for a new house, moving, finding good school systems, finding a good broker or buying or selling a home.

Please add a new Stack Exchange site for this.

Comment: Currently real-estate questions can be asked at https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All StackExchange proposals are handled over on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

> Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone. It’s where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like Stack Overflow. Here you can:
>     - Get involved in the process. Help sites get off the ground by defining what’s on- and off-topic, recruiting a critical mass of experts, and committing to the site’s success.
>    - Propose new Q&A sites. If you have an idea for an expert Q&A site, propose it here.

And there is already a proposal for a [Real Estate site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8744/real-estate) waiting for you to follow!

Comment: The only danger with this is that all the questions are "too localised" as they are, by nature, specific to a locality be it in the US, UK or where ever.

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah, valid concern.  But that's what Area 51 is for, to make sure all proposals are valid and will work with the SE system.  A possible solution would be to have an SE RealEstate site for each country and users could just tag questions with the relevant city for localised content?  Not sure if that will work but worth thinking about.